# Reading CSV file to dataframe in r

Tags: r, read.csv

I have the following CSV file:

```
D1                Diff
20/11/2014 16:00    0
20/11/2014 17:00    0.01
20/11/2014 18:00    0.04
20/11/2014 19:00    0.03
```

Where D1 is a date with time. When I use the following command:

```
ts1<-read.csv (file.choose(), row.names=1 )
```

result:

```
> head (ts1)
                 Diff
20/11/2014 16:00 0.00
20/11/2014 17:00 0.01
20/11/2014 18:00 0.04
20/11/2014 19:00 0.03
20/11/2014 20:00 0.02
20/11/2014 21:00 0.03
```

Why does the first column header (D1) is ignored?

Comment: Because row names are not a column. By specifying `row.names=1` the first column in the csv file is converted into the name of the rows.

Comment: should be: ts1<-read.csv (file.choose()). `row.names=1` use the 1st column as rownames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column 1 is not ignored. You asked `read.csv` to make it into rownames.